# Redis cache - Reading from cache returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, redis, webforms

I am following an article from codeproject to implement Redis, it suffice my purpose of caching.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1120038/A-simple-Csharp-cache-component-using-Redis-as-pro

I am able to save data in Redis cache, if I query the cache through terminal (redis-cli), I am able to see the List which is stored with data.
Code for setting data to Redis cache

```
 private void setDataToRedis()
    {
        try
        {
            ICacheProvider _cacheProvider = new RedisCacheProvider();

            List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person(1, "Joe", new List<Contact>()
                {
                    new Contact("1", "123456789"),
                    new Contact("3", "234567890")
                })
            };
            _cacheProvider.Remove("Peoples");
            _cacheProvider.Set("Peoples", people);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

[Data in Redis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jxik.png)

But when I am trying to read back in code, it gives a blank object.

[Data not retrieved in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSQwm.png)
Code for reading data from Redis

```
 private void getDataFromRedis()
    {
        ICacheProvider _cacheProvider = new RedisCacheProvider();

        dynamic contacts = "";
        if (_cacheProvider.IsInCache("Peoples"))
        {
            contacts = _cacheProvider.Get<List<Contact>>("Peoples");
          
        }

        
    }
```

Redis cache manager class

```
  public class RedisCacheProvider : ICacheProvider
    {
        RedisEndpoint _endPoint;

        public RedisCacheProvider()
        {
            _endPoint = new RedisEndpoint(RedisConfigurationManager.Config.Host, RedisConfigurationManager.Config.Port, RedisConfigurationManager.Config.Password, RedisConfigurationManager.Config.DatabaseID);
        }

        public void Set<T>(string key, T value)
        {
            this.Set(key, value, TimeSpan.Zero);
        }

        public void Set<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            using (RedisClient client = new RedisClient(_endPoint))
            {
                client.As<T>().SetValue(key, value, timeout);
            }
        }

        public T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            T result = default(T);

            using (RedisClient client = new RedisClient(_endPoint))
            {
                var wrapper = client.As<T>();

                result = wrapper.GetValue(key);
            }

            return result;
        }
        
        public bool Remove(string key)
        {
            bool removed = false;

            using (RedisClient client = new RedisClient(_endPoint))
            {
                removed = client.Remove(key);
            }

            return removed;
        }

        public bool IsInCache(string key)
        {
            bool isInCache = false;

            using (RedisClient client = new RedisClient(_endPoint))
            {
                isInCache = client.ContainsKey(key);
            }

            return isInCache;
        }
    }
```

Can someone point me where is it going wrong?

Comment: You're storing a list of Peoples but trying to retrieve a list of Contacts.  That won't work.  You need to store and retrieve like objects when a library is handling your intermediary serialization like this.